# flex swfloader: can i control the volume of the application i'm loading?

Tags: apache-flex, swfloader

i have a flex application that loads flash files using SWFLoader. is there a way to control the audio volume in that swf from my flex application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `SoundTransform` like this.

```
var soundTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(volume);
swfLoader.soundTransform = soundTransform;
```

The volume should be a Number between 0 and 1.
Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: looks great, gonna test it and let ya know.